# Loop array and change value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

With the below code I'm looping an array and if condition met to change array value. I'm receiving an error 424 on the line of changing value. Any ideas?

```
sub test()

    Dim arrAccSof As Variant

    arrAccSof = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(MaxRowAccSof, 4))

    For j = LBound(arrAccSof) To UBound(arrAccSof)

        If IsEmpty(arrAccSof(j, 3)) Then
            arrAccSof(j, 3).Value = 0
        End If
        If IsEmpty(arrAccSof(j, 4)) Then
            arrAccSof(j, 4).Value = 0
        End If

    Next j

end sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array item does not have a `.Value` it must be `arrAccSof(j, 3) = 0`. If you read values into an array like

```
arrAccSof = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(MaxRowAccSof, 4))
```

it is the same as using

```
arrAccSof = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(MaxRowAccSof, 4)).Value
```

and the array does only represent the **values** of the range but not a range object.

Note that if you change the values in the array they do not get changed in the cells automatically, unless you write the array values back to the cells in the end:

```
.Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(MaxRowAccSof, 4)).Value = arrAccSof
```

---

In comparison if you do

```
Dim AccSof As Range
Set AccSof = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(MaxRowAccSof, 4))
```

then `AccSof` is a referenece to the actual range object that can be used like the range itself:

```
AccSof(j, 3).Value = 0
```

This changes the cell value *immediately*.

But note that the first approach using the array is faster. I added this just to explain the difference.

Comment: Concise & helpful :-)